# Retrieve the contents of DataSource from the ComboBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a combobox that I bind to a list of objects with three properties: `int a`, `int b`, and `string x`. When bound I set `DataTextField` to `x` and `DataValueField` to `a`. What I want to do is get the value of `b` in the code-behind after the collection has been bound to the list. I do not want to use ViewState. Can I possibly use reflection? Something like this?

```
var dataSource = ddlTest.GetDataSource();
var newDataSource = dataSource.GetType().GetProperty("_dataSource", 
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: do you want to get only single row's value or all row's value?

Comment: Please show more of your code, for example the class of your DataSource. When do you want to retrieve the content of the DataSource? After postback there is no `b` anymore.

Comment: I want to get all rows. I am making a custom property on this control that will set the values of B in the collection to another property. So I need it to be accessed when I override the DataBind()

Comment: Is this just a regular ASP.NET `DropDownList`?

Comment: Adding an attribute sounds like the only approach that might work, since you want a value that is not being bound (key/value) to the control and you don't want to use ViewState to store the DataSource.  If you don't like that, you could merge a & B before binding then parse in your code-behind or re-query the DS on the server if your key/value is a unique value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about this, but you *might* be able to add `b` as a custom attribute to the `ListItem`. Try something like this and see if it works:

```
var table = new DataTable("TableName"); 

//bind the dropdown to the result set
dropDownList.DataSource = table;
dropDownList.DataBind();

//iterate through the datasource and add custom attributes for each item in the list
table.AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach(r => 
    dropDownList.Items.FindByValue(r.Field<int>("a").ToString()).Attributes["data-field"] = r.Field<int>("b").ToString());
```

If you'd prefer to use a regular foreach loop:

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    var item = dropDownList.FindByValue(row.Field<int>("a").ToString());
    if (item != null)
    {
        item.Attributes["data-value"] = row.Field<int>("b").ToString();
    }
}
```

If adding custom attributes doesn't work and you don't want to use ViewState, you might have to store both `a` and `b` in the value field, separated by a delimeter. This can be a pain because you'll have to parse the items to get the values, but given your requirements that might be the best option if the custom attributes don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that approach should work.  But, to get a property value with reflection you have to do this:

```
var dataSource = ddlTest.DataSource;
PropertyInfo property = dataSource.GetType().GetProperty("b", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var bValue = property.GetValue(dataSource, null);
```

**EDIT**
I think the problem is that we didn't account for the fact that the data source is an array/list.  I got this to work as follows:

```
var data = (IEnumerable<object>)ddlTest.DataSource;        
Type t = typeof(MyClass);
var item = data.ToArray()[0];
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty("b");
int val = (int)pi.GetValue(item, null);
```

This is after I had set the data source like this in the Page_Init:

```
var data = new List<MyClass> { new MyClass() { a = 1, b = 2, x = "testing" } };
ddl.DataSource = data;
ddl.DataBind();
```

Comment: That is what I was thinking but when I do that "property" comes back as null. Any ideas?

Comment: @JonathanO check out my edit above.  I think this should work.